# vertx NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/EventLoopGroup

Tags: vert.x

this is probably a stupid question, but which jar needs to be referenced besides vertx-core jar in order to run a simple verticle example. I have code like this:

```
package examples.vertx;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;  
public class VertxApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        vertx.deployVerticle(new MyVerticle("name1"), stringAsyncResult -> {
            System.out.println("MyVerticle deployed");
        });
    }
}
```

and

```
package examples.vertx; 
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;   
public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private String name = null;

    public MyVerticle(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {
        System.out.println("MyVerticle started!");

        vertx.eventBus().consumer("test", message -> {
            System.out.println(this.name + " received message: " + message.body());
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Future stopFuture) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("MyVerticle stopped!");
    }
}
```

and searched through the vertx documentation but can't see which jar I ought to be referencing besides vertx-core jar. When I run the code I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/EventLoopGroup
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:34)
    at io.vertx.core.Vertx.vertx(Vertx.java:78)
    at examples.vertx.VertxApp.main(VertxApp.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: You also need to include netty. http://netty.io/downloads.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks! I needed netty buffer, common and transport jars

[image: refs]